# Ordered data structure with O(1) lookup and allowed duplicates in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that will allow me to test if an element exists within it in O(1) time as such:

```py
if value in my_data_structure:
    pass
```

However, I need it to be able to keep its order of inserted elements, so I can access them via index or any other way.

The closest I found from a similar question was a multiset, to which in Python a Counter is the closest, but those don't keep any semblance of order and the duplicates are 'aggregated'.

Does anything like this exist at all, even outside of Python, so I could program it myself?

Comment: Sounds like a composition of a list and a set.  You don't mention how fast other operations need to be, though...

Comment: The other operations wouldn't matter as much, as I would be checking the data structure significantly more often than inserting, and I won't need to delete any elements.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like you just want a list and a set then.  Every time you insert an item, add it to the set.  Use the set for lookups by value and use the list for lookups by index.  Easy peasy.

Comment: You clearly can't get O(1) lookup.  That's impossible in the general case.  A balanced tree would give you O(log N) lookup, but doesn't retain insertion order.  A hash table could get you nearly O(1), but you'd have to track the ordering some other way.

Comment: @Samwise That works I suppose. I could create a class that composes them into a new data structure

Comment: If duplicates are allowed, how does looking up a value work - does it return the first?

Comment: @TimRoberts well, the built-in hashmap maintains insertion order

Comment: @balmy In my case I don't need to look up the specific index of an item, I just need to know whether it exists inside the data structure or not. You could implement the list's `.index()` function in addition to the ones I did in my answer below over the list, in which case the answer would be that the index of the first matching element is returned, but this is an O(N) time operation

Comment: Btw, `collections.Counter` objects do maintain order in Python 3.6+ (3.7+ by language guarantee)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Yes, it does so now, and it must be doing so by tracking the insertion order in a separate index.  It's the only way.

Comment: @TimRoberts yep, wasn't disagreeing with you.  It is implemented quite cleverly, too.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Samwise, we can make a set and list composition, so I made a simple one that does what is needed. This ensures amortized O(1) insertion and O(1) access for both checking if an element exists in it, and to retrieve the element by index:

```py
class SetListComposite:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = []
        self.s = set()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.ls[key]
    
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.s

    def append(self, val):
        self.ls.append(val)
        self.s.add(val)
```